# How do I comply with lifetime bounds when passing functions as argument?

Tags: generics, rust, lifetime, borrowing

### Original Issue

This piece of code is relatively similar to the piece of code I am trying to fix. I've also asked this on the [Rust user's forum](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/confusing-errors-regarding-types-and-lifetimes/42146?u=alfriadox).

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b593a3172abb52d76919cd8e351d8ea7)

```
/// assume this function can't be modified.
fn foo<A>(
    f1: impl Fn(&str) -> Result<(&str, A), ()>,
    base: &str,
    f2: impl Fn(A) -> bool
) {
    let s: String = base.to_owned();
    let option = Some(s.as_ref());
    let mapped = option.map(f1);
    let r = mapped.unwrap();
    let (rem, prod) = r.unwrap();
    assert!(f2(prod));
    assert_eq!(rem.len(), 0);
}


fn main() {
    fn bar<'a>(s: &'a str) -> Result<(&'a str, &'a str), ()> {
        Ok((&s[..1], &s[..]))
    }


    fn baz(s: &str) -> Result<(&str, &str), ()> {
        Ok((&s[..1], &s[..]))
    }

    foo(bar, "string", |s| s.len() == 5); // fails to compile

    foo(baz, "string", |s| s.len() == 5); // fails to compile 
}
```

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `for<'r> <for<'a> fn(&'a str) -> std::result::Result<(&'a str, &'a str), ()> {main::bar} as std::ops::FnOnce<(&'r str,)>>::Output == std::result::Result<(&'r str, _), ()>`
  --> src/main.rs:27:5
   |
2  | fn foo<A>(
   |    ---
3  |     f1: impl Fn(&str) -> Result<(&str, A), ()>,
   |                          --------------------- required by this bound in `foo`
...
27 |     foo(bar, "string", |s| s.len() == 5); // fails to compile
   |     ^^^ expected bound lifetime parameter, found concrete lifetime
```

### Edit:

Based on recommendations from a number of people here, on the [internals thread I made](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/lifetime-parameters-in-generic-types-and-their-relation-to-higher-order-trait-bounds/12285?u=alfriadox), and on the rust user forum, I changed my code to simplify it by using a wrapper trait.

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=010f7fbb459e4ed43cbdee148b8f97ab)

```
trait Parser<'s> {
    type Output;

    fn call(&self, input: &'s str) -> (&'s str, Self::Output);
}

impl<'s, F, T> Parser<'s> for F
where F: Fn(&'s str) -> (&'s str, T) {
    type Output = T;
    fn call(&self, input: &'s str) -> (&'s str, T) {
        self(input)
    }
}

fn foo<F1, F2>(
    f1: F1,
    base: &'static str,
    f2: F2
) 
where 
    F1: for<'a> Parser<'a>,
    F2: FnOnce(&<F1 as Parser>::Output) -> bool
{
    // These two lines cannot be changed.
    let s: String = base.to_owned();
    let str_ref = s.as_ref();

    let (remaining, produced) = f1.call(str_ref);
    assert!(f2(&produced));
    assert_eq!(remaining.len(), 0);
}

struct Wrapper<'a>(&'a str);

fn main() {
    fn bar<'a>(s: &'a str) -> (&'a str, &'a str) {
        (&s[..1], &s[..])
    }

    fn baz<'a>(s: &'a str) -> (&'a str, Wrapper<'a>) {
        (&s[..1], Wrapper(&s[..]))
    }

    foo(bar, "string", |s| s.len() == 5); // fails to compile

    foo(baz, "string", |s| s.0.len() == 5); // fails to compile 
}
```

this code generates an internal compiler error currently:

```
error: internal compiler error: src/librustc_infer/traits/codegen/mod.rs:61: Encountered error `OutputTypeParameterMismatch(Binder(<[closure@src/main.rs:45:24: 45:40] as std::ops::FnOnce<(&<for<'a> fn(&'a str) -> (&'a str, &'a str) {main::bar} as Parser<'_>>::Output,)>>), Binder(<[closure@src/main.rs:45:24: 45:40] as std::ops::FnOnce<(&&str,)>>), Sorts(ExpectedFound { expected: &str, found: <for<'a> fn(&'a str) -> (&'a str, &'a str) {main::bar} as Parser<'_>>::Output }))` selecting `Binder(<[closure@src/main.rs:45:24: 45:40] as std::ops::FnOnce<(&&str,)>>)` during codegen

thread 'rustc' panicked at 'Box<Any>', src/librustc_errors/lib.rs:875:9
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace

note: the compiler unexpectedly panicked. this is a bug.

note: we would appreciate a bug report: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#bug-reports

note: rustc 1.43.0 (4fb7144ed 2020-04-20) running on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

note: compiler flags: -C codegen-units=1 -C debuginfo=2 --crate-type bin

note: some of the compiler flags provided by cargo are hidden

error: aborting due to previous error

error: could not compile `playground`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

I have made a bug report [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/71955).

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what the expected behaviour and the problem is? It's great that you've included a playground link, but we shouldn't have to run the playground to guess what you're asking about.

Comment: The `Fn` trait doesn't seem to be flexible enough to express this, so you should define your own trait instead.

Comment: I just saw the comment "assume this function can't be modified" on the playground. In that case, the function simply can't take the function you want to pass in. `A` needs to have static lifetime, so make it some kind of "owned" type (in this case a `String`).

Comment: @PeterHall Ok well then assuming that function could be modified, what modifications would you make?

Comment: @AntoniaCalia-Bogan one suggestion is in my answer below. But we're talking about a generic function here, so it really depends on your anticipated bounds on the genericity.

Comment: It's hard to answer multiple questions made in one post. Please separate them into multiple questions so that we can help you better and so that your questions will help others in the future that have one of the same questions as you!

Answer (score 2):

Look at the first function argument:

```
f1: impl Fn(&str) -> Result<(&str, A), ()>,
```

Where could a value of type `A` come from? It has to be either:

- derived from the `str` in the argument, or
- plucked from nowhere, which would mean it is `'static`

But `A` is declared for `foo`, not for the specific `f1` argument. This means that the lifetime of `A` cannot depend on the argument of `f1`. But that is exactly what `bar` and `baz` do.

So what can you do? Given your requirement of "assume this function can't be modified", you are stuck with changing `bar` and `baz` so that the type of `A` is static. This gives you the choice of a newly allocated `String`  or a `&'static str`:

```
fn bar<'a>(s: &'a str) -> Result<(&'a str, String), ()> {
    Ok((&s[..1], s[..].to_owned()))
}
```

Or:

```
fn bar<'a>(s: &'a str) -> Result<(&'a str, &'static str), ()> {
    Ok((&s[..1], "hello"))
}
```

---

If you *were* able to change the type signature of `foo`, you could use references to `A` in the argument functions' signatures, which would let you describe their lifetimes in relation to their other arguments:

E.g.:

```
fn foo<A: ?Sized>(
    f1: impl Fn(&str) -> Result<(&str, &A), ()>,
    base: &str,
    f2: impl Fn(&A) -> bool
) {
    unimplemented!()
}
```

Which is equivalent to the following, without lifetime elision:

```
fn foo<A: ?Sized>(
    f1: impl for<'a> Fn(&'a str) -> Result<(&'a str, &'a A), ()>,
    base: &str,
    f2: impl for<'a> Fn(&'a A) -> bool
) {
    unimplemented!()
}
```

Note that the type signature of `f1`  now expresses an association between the lifetime of the input `&str` and the `&A` in the result.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who reads through this later on and wonders if I ever found a workaround, I did!

This workaround involves placing the state referenced by the function calls into a `Context` structure. Because of the current issues with Higher Rank Trait Bounds (HRTBs), this workaround avoids them entirely. Instead, we refactor object initialization (which could be expensive) into the Context's constructor. The context completely owns the function state. This is fine though, since the function only needs a reference to that state, not ownership. Whenever we need to call the function, we pass it to the Context's call function, which ensures that the lifetime of the arguments to the function and it's output matches the lifetime of the context in/on which it runs.

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1192bfad5f1d35eabac5cd25b0903aee)

```rust
// Workaround code: the state of the function is placed 
// into a struct so that all of the references are valid
// for the lifetime of of &self. This way concrete lifetimes
// can be used because all lifetimes start on the function 
// call, rather than several statements into the function. 
//
// This work around eliminates the need for Higher Ranked 
// Trait Bounds (HRTBs), since all lifetimes are instantiated
// on function initialization.

struct Wrapper<'a>(&'a str);

struct ParserContext {
    inner: String
}

impl ParserContext {
    fn new(base: &str) -> Self {Self {inner: base.to_owned()}}

    fn call<'a, O>(
        &'a self, 
        f1: fn(&'a str) -> (&'a str, O),
        f2: fn(O) -> bool,
    ) {
        let (remaining, produced) = f1(self.inner.as_str());
        assert_eq!(remaining.len(), 0);
        assert!(f2(produced));
    }
}


fn main() {
    fn bar(s: &str) -> (&str, &str) {
        (&s[..0], &s[..])
    }

    fn baz(s: &str) -> (&str, Wrapper) {
        (&s[..0], Wrapper(&s[..]))
    }


    // I tried to extract the section below into its
    // own function previously (foo) but this would
    // always inevitably fail because of lifetime issues.
    // this work around only adds one line of code to the calling
    // function to create the context to hold the state 
    // used by the functions passed to `call`, so this 
    // is an acceptable, and rather eloquent work around.
    let pc = ParserContext::new("string");

    pc.call(bar, |s| s.len() == 6);
    pc.call(baz, |s| s.0.len() == 6);
}
```